# Increment React Counters in a mapped list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to increment and decrement values using a single onChange and handleIncrement in a mapped functional component.

when the click function runs it updates all the listed inputs with the same value.

please, how can i get them to update each individually?

I am still quite the noob.

here is my code:

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    count: 0,
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({
      ...state.count,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return { count: prevState.count + 1 };
    });
  };

  const listings = Consumables.map((list) => (
    <Col lg={4}>
      <Bounce up>
        <Card
          key={list.product}
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "25rem",
            marginTop: "5%",
            textAlign: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Card.Header as="h3">{list.product}</Card.Header>
          <Card.Body>
            {list.productImage}
            <br />
            <br />
            {list.description}
            <br />
            <br />
            {list.weight}
            <h5>Price: {list.price}</h5>
          </Card.Body>
          <Card.Footer>
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <Button variant="danger">-</Button>
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl
                name={list.product}
                type="text"
                value={state.count}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <InputGroup.Append>
                <Button variant="success" onClick={handleIncrement}>
                  +
                </Button>
              </InputGroup.Append>
            </InputGroup>
          </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
      </Bounce>
    </Col>
  ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the index of your counter to be able to increment it individually :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [counters, setCounters] = React.useState([0, 0, 0, 0]);
  const setCount = (index, newCounter) => {
    const newCounters = Object.assign([], counters);
    newCounters[index] = newCounter;
    setCounters(newCounters);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {counters.map((counter, index) => (
        <Counter index={index} counter={counter} setCount={setCount} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Counter = ({ index, counter, setCount }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Counter {index} = {counter}{" "}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(index, counter + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I get the index of the mapped counter, and I give it to the component so I can easily point to the correct counter in the state. The update is done with just one method that take this index as parameter.

Here is the [repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vjt8uw?file=index.js)

Comment: Ahh!!!!! PERFECT! just what I needed thank you so much for you help

Comment: @BrendanPower You're welcome :) Don't hesitate to separate your code into different component. It's clearer and each component can handle their own state if you need to so possibilities are increased

Comment: I was finally able to implement this code to my App... im still not sure as to how exactly it works but it works well! if you are able to help with an broken down explanation of the code you wrote, i would really appreciate it :) Thank in advance!

Comment: @BrendanPower tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: it's okay, i found documentation that helped explain like Object,assign() and getting the index, and how it does so... so no more problems :)

Comment: @BrendanPower Object.assign is just a way to clone your counters (states are immutable, could use lodash 'clonedeep' as well). If it helped then don't hesitate to upvote and check as correct answer that would be nice :)